# SQL MAX((SUM)) combined usage

Tags: sql, sum, max, sql-server-2019

I have two tables:

`EMPLOYEE: ID|DEPARTMENT_ID|CHIEF_ID|NAME|SALARY`

`DEPARTMENT: ID|NAME`

The task here is to get list of departments with total max salary of all employees.

The query I'm trying to use (completes with no results):

```
SELECT s.DEPARTMENT_ID, s.SALARY_SUM
 
FROM (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, SUM(SALARY) SALARY_SUM, w.ID
 
      FROM EMPLOYEE e
 
      JOIN DEPARTMENT w ON  w.ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID 

      GROUP BY e.DEPARTMENT_ID, w.ID) s

WHERE s.SALARY_SUM = (SELECT MAX(SALARY) MaxSum

                    FROM EMPLOYEE w1 

                    WHERE  w1.ID = s.ID)
```

Comment: are you using mysql 8? eslse you need to make the select clause twice

Comment: @nbk sorry, wrong tag. I'm using MS SQL Server 15.0.2080.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you all the Deoatnent that have the highest Sum from their employees

> ```
> CREATE tABLe EMPLOYEE(DEPARTMENT_ID INT, SALARY INT)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe DEPARTMENT(ID int)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE as (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, SUM(SALARY) SALARY_SUM, w.ID
>  
>       FROM EMPLOYEE e
>  
>       JOIN DEPARTMENT w ON  w.ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID 
>
>       GROUP BY e.DEPARTMENT_ID, w.ID)
>      
> SELECT s.DEPARTMENT_ID, s.SALARY_SUM
>  
> FROM CTE s
>
> WHERE s.SALARY_SUM = (SELECT MAX(SALARY_SUM) MaxSum
>
>                     FROM CTE w1 )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> DEPARTMENT_ID | SALARY_SUM
> ------------: | ---------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c83e546bc85beb3f47800406cd00a879)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

I'm getting one department instead of a list, but this is how it should work I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have 4 data sets here.

1. EMPLOYEE e
2. DEPARTMENT w
3. Subquery1 s
4. Subquery2 (where clause)

Data set 3 has salary aggregated by Department ID.
Data set 4 has the largest employee salary for each department.

The Where clause is saying compare 3 to 4 where SALARY_SUM = MaxSum. Because SALARY_SUM is aggregated by Department ID, and MaxSum is the largest individual salary, this where clause will only return results for departments with 1 person (or if people have a salary of $0).

If a department has multiple people with salaries, the SUM of the department's salary will always be greater than the largest individual salary in the department.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying things. Anyways, I don't quite get how to modify the query to get proper results.

Comment: Data set 3 (subquery1 s) should return this as (department, sum salary of that department, department ID). MAX is not necessary for this aggregation. I'd use MAX if I wanted the highest salary in each department and SUM if I want the total salary for each department.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew!